# Using arabic_reshaper and bidi.algorithm in kivymd

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

I am going to make a application with kivymd, which contains Arabic and Persian texts.

According to my searches, to do this, you should use arabic_reshaper and bidi.algorithm and also use a font that supports Persian and Arabic languages.
As a result, I was able to write the code like this, and it supports both Persian and Arabic text well.

```
import kivy.app
import kivy.uix.label
import arabic_reshaper
import bidi.algorithm

class TestApp(kivy.app.App):
 def build(self):
    
    bidi_text = bidi.algorithm.get_display(arabic_reshaper.reshape("میلاد"))
    return kivy.uix.label.Label(text=bidi_text, font_name="arial" , font_size="90sp") 

testApp = TestApp()
testApp.run()
```

[see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vWPRi.png)

Now, My problem is that I want to code my program as follows, in this method I can change the font, but I can not use the method arabic_reshaper and bidi.algorithm, and this causes the output text to be displayed in this way .

```
                from kivymd.app import MDApp
                from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
                from kivymd.uix.label import MDLabel
                from kivy.lang import Builder
                import arabic_reshaper
                import bidi.algorithm


                screen_helper_up = """
                Screen:
                    NavigationLayout:
                        ScreenManager:
                            Screen:
                                BoxLayout:
                                    orientation: 'vertical'
                                    MDToolbar:
                                        title: 'میلاد'
                                        font_name:'arial.ttf'
                                        left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                                        
                                        elevation:10

                                    Widget:
                                    Label:
                                        text: "میلاد"
                                        font_name:'arial.ttf'
                                        markup: True
                                        font_size: 100
                                        color: 0,0,0,1

                        MDNavigationDrawer:
                            id: nav_drawer
                        
                """

                class DemoApp (MDApp):

                    
                    
                    def build(self):
                        
                        screen = Screen()
                        screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper_up)
                        return screen

                    

                DemoApp().run()
```

As you can see in the image below, the font has changed only in Label and in MDToolbar title, Unfortunately, the font has not changed either.

[see the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uupRI.png)

1. How can I use the ... and ... methods to display Persian and Arabic text in the above code?
2. How can I change the font in ...?

Comment: In your code, I didn't see you use `arabic_reshaper` and `bidi.algorithm`

Comment: As I said above, I know in the first method how to use arabic_reshaper and bidi.algorithm But in the second method, I do not know how to use arabic_reshaper and bidi.algorithm. @Xyanight

Answer (score 1):

This is what I have done: In the Kv language, refer the text to a variable (`app.res3`) in the main app:

```
`text:app.res3`

`font_name:'PTBLDHAD'`
```

In the main app, I applied the reshaper module as follows:

```
`text3 = ("الصفحة الرئيسية")` 

reshaped_texts3 = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text3)

res3 = get_display(reshaped_texts3)
```

Answer (score 0):

@aiyad-alreshidi
Thanks for the reply
I edited the code as you said (of course if I got it right) and changed it to this code:

```
            from kivymd.app import MDApp
            from kivymd.uix.screen import Screen
            from kivy.lang import Builder
            import arabic_reshaper
            import bidi.algorithm


            screen_helper_up = """
            Screen:
                NavigationLayout:
                    ScreenManager:
                        Screen:
                            BoxLayout:
                                orientation: 'vertical'

                                MDToolbar:
                                    title: app.res3
                                    font_name:'iran.ttf'
                                    left_action_items: [["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.toggle_nav_drawer()]]
                                    
                                    elevation:10
                                
                                MDTextField: 
                                    text: app.res3
                                    helper_text: app.res3
                                    hint_text: app.res3
                                    font_name: 'iran.ttf'
                                    helper_text_mode: "persistent"
                                    font_size: 30
                                    line_color_focus: self.theme_cls.opposite_bg_normal
                                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.3}
                                    size_hint: (0.5,0.4)
                                    icon_right: "android"
                                    

                                Widget:
                                Label:
                                    text: app.res3
                                    font_name:'iran.ttf'
                                    markup: True
                                    font_size: 100
                                    color: 0,0,0,1

                    MDNavigationDrawer:
                        id: nav_drawer
                    
            """

            class DemoApp (MDApp):

                text3 = ("میلاد")
                reshaped_texts3 = arabic_reshaper.reshape(text3)
                res3 = bidi.algorithm.get_display(reshaped_texts3)
                
                def build(self):
                    
                    screen = Screen()
                    screen = Builder.load_string(screen_helper_up)
                    return screen

                

            DemoApp().run()
```

Unfortunately, As you see in the image below, the font has changed only in Label and in MDToolbar title or also MDTextField (helper_text and hint_text), Again, it has not changed

[image: see the output]