# is there a way to write Persian in python kivy

Tags: python, kivy, farsi

i try to write Persian in python kivy but it is not working.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy import Config
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget


class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Label(text= "فارسی")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: What does "it is not working" mean?

Comment: when t try to write Persian in kivy label it's not print

Comment: What does it print instead? Nothing? Something different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use some Persian font.
I have done it with Arabic text

You can download the font from [here](https://www.fontsc.com/font/download/amiri)

Then use arabic_reshaper library to get it in shape.

```
pip install arabic-reshaper
```

You will also need python-bidi as well to flip the letters

```
pip install python-bidi
```

Refer to this https://github.com/mpcabd/python-arabic-reshaper

**Code**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager,Screen
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy import Config
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
import arabic_reshaper
from bidi.algorithm import get_display

class MainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        reshaped_text = arabic_reshaper.reshape("فارسی")
        bidi_text = get_display(reshaped_text)
        
        return Label(text= bidi_text, font_name='Amiri-Regular.ttf', font_size=30)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MainApp().run()
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: can i write Persian also in kv file

Comment: Yes you can. You need to reshape it and bidi it then just include the font. font_name: 'Amiri-Regular.ttf' and the text as a variable.

Answer (score 0):

Use Kivyir for Persian/Farsi.

```
pip install kivyir --user
```

[Link GitHub](https://www.github.com/goldaaa/kivyir)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).